# VI won't let me save my vimrc file

Tags: permissions, vim, vimrc

I have changed the permissions to allow for:

```
-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root 2214 Oct  4 09:45 vimrc
```

and it still won't let me save to the file. I only have one user on this box and it has admin rights.  Everytime I make changes to the file and try and save it tells me I'm trying to make changes to a read only file and to hit `!` to override.  When I do that and hit `!ZZ` it still doesn't save.

Comment: Where is that file located? As far as I kow it shoud be named `.vimrc`, not `vimrc`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root` means the file belongs to the root user and that only him and users from the group 'root' may write to it.

You can use your sudo powers and run `sudo vim vimrc` or you could change the owner with `sudo chown <insert-your-username-here> vimrc` and then edit it with `vim vimrc`

Comment: to use the chown command do i need to use the sudo command as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use `:w!` to override read-only, instead.
Edit the file with `sudo vi <filename>` if necessary.

Also, it looks like you may be trying to edit `/etc/vim/vimrc`.  Don't do that ; edit ~/.vimrc (or /home/youruser/.vimrc) instead.